# Capybara Webkit - Unable to start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt4, qmake, capybara-webkit

After pulling down an existing Rails project to my local machine, running the test suite throws an error when trying to run our feature tests which use the capybara-webkit gem. **The tests run fine on all the other dev machines, as well as Codeship**, so it has been narrowed down to my machine.

**The first error when running the specs:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448myproject/gems/capybara-webkit-1.2.0/bin/webkit_server
  Reason: image not found
```

From what I can gather, it's looking for the webkit_server executable and can't find it. So I did a search for it myself and found it here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4
```

So the discrepancy here is in `@rpath` from what I can tell. I guess the question here is where is `@rpath` pointing, and where should my `QtWebkit.framework` be?

**The second error when running the specs:**

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Can't assign requested address - connect(2)
  occurred at /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myproject/gems/capybara-webkit-1.2.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:84:in `initialize'
```

I'm assuming this is a byproduct of the previous error, but have included it anyway.

**So far, we've done a few other things to try and remedy the situation:**

- Removed and reinstalled Qt4 using Homebrew (via this post: 
  [Error using capybara-webkit (really QtWebKit webkit_server) on MacOS X due to libpng version incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244688/error-using-capybara-webkit-really-qtwebkit-webkit-server-on-macos-x-due-to-li))
- Updated the capybara-webkit gem to `1.2.0` from `1.0.0`
- Verified that the output of `which QMake` makes sense (shows `/usr/local/bin/QMake`)
- Reinstalled X11
- Edit: Just installed Qt from source - No luck

Answer (score 1):

After searched for a long time, I finally found that capybara-webkit version is the problem. So update your gem capybara-webkit should fix this. At least it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the cheat code to increase the `WEBKIT_SERVER_START_TIMEOUT` constant time.

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|                                             
   config.class.parent::Connection.send(:remove_const,:WEBKIT_SERVER_START_TIMEOUT)   
   config.class.parent::Connection::WEBKIT_SERVER_START_TIMEOUT = 30                  
end
```